# MVC3 Multi Model Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a multi-Model form and have more than one question so i will start with the first question:
 In my view of a list i have an action link that opens the form. I need this link to open like this.

/AuditSchedule/Audit/1192/Section/1

Currently the link is like this

/AuditSchedule/Audit/1192/Section

Here is my code for the action link

```
 grid.Column(format: (tracking) => Html.ActionLink("Select", "Audit", new { id = tracking.AuditScheduleID })),
```

I have a link setup in my Global.asax

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "AuditSchedule", // Route name

            "AuditSchedule/Audit/{id}/Section/{section}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "AuditSchedule", action = "Audit", id = UrlParameter.Optional, section = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults

        );
```

The section will always be 1. 
How do i get this link to show that?

Question 2
 I have the form view populate questions from selecting the side menu. I also have a view model that i created for some checkboxes to populate from a table that has the selections in it. 
 If i add a record with the ID of the AuditSchedule they populate. This is good. However i need each one of these questions to put the selected in the table of Answers for each question. I have added a (get set) for the MainQuestionID however it shows up all zeros.

How do i get this to populate so that it knows which question it is for and insert it into the table of questions?

Here is the code:

```
namespace QQAForm.ViewModels
{
public class AuditFormEdit
{
    public virtual int MainQuestionID { get; set; }

    public List<SubcategoryHelper> SubcategoryHelperGet { get; set; }

    public class SubcategoryHelper : Models.SubCategory
    {
        public SubcategoryHelper(Models.SubCategory subCat)
        {
            this.SubCategoryID = subCat.SubCategoryID;
            this.SubcategoryName = subCat.SubcategoryName;
        }

    }


    public Models.MainAnswer ScoreInstance { get; set; }

    public List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper> ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList { get; set; }

    public void InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList(List<Models.Score> ScoreList)
    {
        if (this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList == null)
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList = new List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper>();

        if (ScoreList != null
            && this.ScoreInstance != null)
        {
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Clear();
            ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper scoreCardCheckBoxHelper;
            string scoreTypes =
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ScoreInstance.Score) ?
                string.Empty : this.ScoreInstance.Score;
            foreach (Models.Score scoreType in ScoreList)
            {
                scoreCardCheckBoxHelper = new ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(scoreType);
                if (scoreTypes.Contains(scoreType.ScoreName))
                    scoreCardCheckBoxHelper.Checked = true;
                this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Add(scoreCardCheckBoxHelper);
            }
        }
    }


    public void PopulateCheckBoxsToScores()
    {
        this.ScoreInstance.Score = string.Empty;
        var scoreType = this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Where(x => x.Checked)
                              .Select<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper, string>(x => x.ScoreName)
                              .AsEnumerable();
        this.ScoreInstance.Score = string.Join(", ", scoreType);
    }


    public class ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper : Models.Score
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper() : base() { }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(Models.Score score)
        {
            this.ScoreID = score.ScoreID;
            this.ScoreName = score.ScoreName;
        }
    }



}
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@{ Layout = null; }
@model QQAForm.ViewModels.AuditFormEdit

        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MainQuestionID)
        <br />
        @for (int index = 0; index < Model.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Count; index++)
        {

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].Checked)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index], Model.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].ScoreName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].ScoreID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].ScoreName)
            <br />

        }
```

Here is the  controller:

```
        //get
    public ActionResult _ScoreSection(int id)
    {
        AuditFormEdit viewModel = new AuditFormEdit();
        viewModel.ScoreInstance = _db.MainAnswers.Single(r => r.AuditScheduleID == id);
        //_db.SubCategories.Single(r => r.SubCategoryID == Section);
        viewModel.InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList(_db.Scores.ToList());
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // get
    public ActionResult _Forms(int section)
    {
        var subCatToDisplay = _db.SubCategories.Single(r => r.SubCategoryID == section);
        return View(subCatToDisplay);
    }



    //post
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _Forms(AuditFormEdit viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.PopulateCheckBoxsToScores();
            _db.Entry(viewModel.ScoreInstance).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("/");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

here is the results Layout View:
[image]

I currently have all of this pulled into a layout via partials etc. if there is an easier way or cleaner way to do this let me know.

thanks

Comment: It looks like you may not have an input to carry Model.MainQuestionID into the POST action. There is a DisplayFor, but you probably want an EditorFor, too, or store it in an Html.Hidden.

Comment: I changed the: public virtual int MainQuestionID { get; set; }
to public Models.MainQuestion MainQuestionID { get; set; } now the zero's disappear and i have nothing. If i add the editor for i have all the fields in the table populate but nothing appears in it. My mainquestion comes from a partial and then of course the score part is another partial. Do i need to incorporate the mainquestion with score int he view model? if so not sure then if that will break code that works already.